# How can I avoid using hidden fields to pass data from PHP to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developping a website with some serious Javascript involved and I have to use generated data from PHP in my JS code.

For example, to be able to use my page ID in JS, I proceed like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pageId" value="<?php echo $page->getId() ?>" />
<button id="runJs">RUN</button>
```

And in my javascript (with jQuery):

```
$(function() {
  $('#runJs').click(function() {
    var id = $('#pageId').val();
  });
});
```

It works, but is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since HTML5, one can now add user-made attributes to any HTML tag **as long as it starts with `data-`**.

In HTML5:

```
<button id="runJs" data-pageId="<?php echo $page->getId() ?>">RUN</button>
```

In JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('#runJs').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-pageId');
  });
});
```

Or, as said **Eric Martinez** in the comments, using jQuery:

```
var id = $(this).data('pageId');
```

Passing data this way is cleaner for two reasons:

1. It is not using a side tag that could be confusing.
2. The data you pass is included in the button, which means another button with its own `data-XXX` can use the same JS function, even on the same page.

**Example**

HTML:

```
<button data-value="5">Square it!</button>
<button data-value="7">Square it!</button>
<button data-value="12">Square it!</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
    alert(value * value); // Shows 25, 49 or 144 depending of the button pressed.
  });
});
```

The function doesn't know the button. The buttons don't even need an ID as long as JS is involved.

Comment: He can even use [jQuery.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) for that kind of tags.

Comment: Thanks @EricMartinez, I added your remark in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create variables inside the  tag. Like this:

```
<script>
    var pageId = '<?php echo $page->getId(); ?>';
</script>
```

Later in your script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#runJs').click(function() {
        var id = pageId;
    });
});
```